# Server Error on asmx application trying different file

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2012, asp.net

Right now I'm trying to bring back to life an existing IIS server (I have the files from a broken server).

After selecting the root, several ASP files work correctly, but I have an application with this output

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebService1.Global'.

Source Error:
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="WebService1.Global" %>
```

I want to load this path:

```
http://localhost/wsCriativo/wscriativo.asmx
```

But it is trying to load the `/global.asax` file and get this error.

I must say those files were working on the previous server so it must be a configuration problem with IIS.

**Info: IIS 8.5, Windows Server 2012 x64**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if you added the application "wscriativo" (the name you provided in the URL) to some application pool.

I had the same problem and this was my problem.

Probably you just created the wwwroot and this folder has other broken applications inside it.

Add one application for each subfolder you want to run. This way you avoid using the broken applications.

If you got the application from an old IIS, also check the asp version. In my case I had to use v2.0 instead of v4.0.

Good luck!